# What is the significance of the fact that $L^\infty$ is a dual space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Is there some significance to the fact that $L^\infty$ is a dual space?   How might this be important or significant in some way?

More precisely, it's dual to $L^1$, but that's not a point I necessarily wanted to concentrate on in my question.

Comment: What do you view as significant or important? Put it this way, in your research have you ever found it useful to know that a particular Banach space is a dual space?

Comment: Also: what is wrong with the answer you received (and accepted) when you asked this question on MSE? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3727120/is-there-some-reason-that-the-fact-that-l-infty-is-the-dual-space-of-l1-is

Comment: Likely relevant context: Sullivan's statement that Connes is excited about this fact, at 2:45 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixc0TNfT0ks

Comment: @user_1789 "He has given us a shoe! The shoe is the sign!" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka9mfZbTFbk